getting the status as NOT_FOUND even though my DB contains the data

DbQueryStatus
Results from mongo query find id

@GetMapping(value = "/getSongTitleById/{songId}")
  public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getSongTitleById(@PathVariable("songId") String songId,
      HttpServletRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    response.put("path", String.format("GET %s", Utils.getUrl(request)));

    DbQueryStatus dbQueryStatus = songDal.getSongTitleById(songId);

    response.put("message", dbQueryStatus.getMessage());
    response = Utils.setResponseStatus(response, dbQueryStatus.getdbQueryExecResult(), dbQueryStatus.getData());

    return response;
  }

this is my Utils.java file
package com.csc301.songmicroservice;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

import okhttp3.RequestBody;

public class Utils {

  public static RequestBody emptyRequestBody = RequestBody.create("",null);

  // Used to determine path that was called from within each REST route, you don't
  // need to modify this
  public static String getUrl(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String requestUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString();
    String queryString = req.getQueryString();

    if (queryString != null) {
      requestUrl += "?" + queryString;
    }
    return requestUrl;
  }

  // Sets the response status and data for a response from the server. You will
  // not always be able to use this function
  public static Map<String, Object> setResponseStatus(Map<String, Object> response, DbQueryExecResult dbQueryExecResult,
      Object data) {
    switch (dbQueryExecResult) {
      case QUERY_OK:
        response.put("status", HttpStatus.OK);
        if (data != null) {
          response.put("data", data);
        }
        break;
      case QUERY_ERROR_NOT_FOUND:
        response.put("status", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        break;
      case QUERY_ERROR_GENERIC:
        response.put("status", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        break;
    }

    return response;
  }
}

My mongodb is connected but still it gives the error
there are many other methods such as addSong,deleteSongById, etc,
It shows the status as 200 OK, but under body it shows as status:"NOT_FOUND" when i am testing the api on POSTMAN
Not really sure what's wrong
would really appreciate your help in this

What data does it have on dbQueryStatus? Can you paste it?

I have added the DbQueryStatus, plz check

Can you add the result you are getting from mongo query

I have put up the result from the mongo query

i hope that is what u meant, finding the song details from song id; result from mongo query

Want to see what exactly was your issue? I want to see the results in debugger

Hey Rahul, is there a way u can help me either through discord or any other way, apparently its asking me to take this discussion to chat, but I don't have enough reputations

Your question doesn't include the details where anyone can understand what exactly is happening. Add enough details to explain this line "It shows the status as 200 OK, but under body it shows as status:"NOT_FOUND""
